# Read complex JSON in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json object and I would like to read it (access some data from it)

how can I do it in Javascript please ?

```
var allSites = 
  {"oldSites":
        [ 
            {
                "site0" : "http://site0.com/", 
                "site1" : "http://site1.com/",
                "site2" : "http://site2.com/" 
            }
        ],
    "newSites":
        [
            {
                "site0" : "http://site0/new", 
                "site1" : "http://site1/new", 
                "site2" : "http://site2/new"
            }
        ]
  };
```

This is what I did but I get undefined.

```
var allSites = eval(allSites);
alert(allSites.oldSites.site0);
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is not a JSON object, since JSON is only a formatting convention to represent **JAVASCRIPT LITERAL OBJECTS** under the form of a **STRING**. Do that without `eval`ing the object(and anyway with a JSON string you should use `JSON.parse`)

Comment: try this : alert(allSites.oldSites[0].site0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your object is defined like you have described, it is not JSON, you do not need to use `eval`.

Then, since `oldSites` is an array, you have to index it, like `oldSites[0]` to get the first value.

Then, get the `site0` key of the object retrieved.

So you should use: **`allSites.oldSites[0].site0`**

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
allSites.oldSites[0].site0
```

`allSites.oldSites` is an array. So you have to iterate using index

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the square brackets which make oldSites an array

```
var allSites = 
  {"oldSites":

            {
                "site0" : "http://site0.com/", 
                "site1" : "http://site1.com/",
                "site2" : "http://site2.com/" 
            }
        ,
    "newSites":

            {
                "site0" : "http://site0/new", 
                "site1" : "http://site1/new", 
                "site2" : "http://site2/new"
            }

  };
```

Comment: I used this  solution working good however I need for some reason (a coding reason) to access the site0 index like this : `allSites.oldSites[0]` instead of `allSites.oldSites.site0`  is it possible?

Comment: your eval statment had 'allSites.oldSites.site0' so removing the `[` `]` was the option, but yes it depends on requirements :)